# Best way to send json to front end in python

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I don't have much experience with python and I am looking for a clean way to send a json(which is the result of a query )to the front end and have structred nice.

The query looks like this:

```
def myquery(time1, time 2):
    query_basictable = """
    Select ...
     my_data = pd.read_sql(sql=query_basictable, con=engine)

    return my_data.to_json()
```

Now here is where I belive I am mistaking:

```
df_my_data=myquery(time1, time 2)
data = df_my_data
```

The json:

```
data_out = {}
data_out['datas']={}
data_out['datas']['stores']= data
```

And in the front end:

```
<td colspan="2" class="{{ data['datas']['stores']}}">
                    <h4><b>Stores</b></h1>
                    <h3>{{ data['datas']['stores'] }}</h3>
                </td>
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"Store":{"0":"Store_013","1":"Store_03"}}
```

What am I doing wrong in order to have something nice like:

```
Store_013
Store_03
```

Comment: are you using any web framework with python? Please mention about that in question

Comment: you can use `json.dumps(data)`, send it to front-end and use javascripts way of loading json.

Comment: Sorry @MoinuddinQuadri I've should mentioned this in the question. I am using Flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jinja template can receive the dictionary and iterate over it using [iteritems()](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for) and for loop

```
<ul>
    {% for key, value in dataout.iteritems() %}
        <li>{{value}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here **dataout** is send using `render_template()` in view function as follow:

```
@app.route('/yoururl')
def view_name():
    # Other logics here
    return render_template('some.html', dataout=dataout)
```

For this at least create an empty `some.html` file (under **templates** directory)